# Could an Excel dropdown box behave as a ListBox with checkboxes for Multi Selection?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, activex, spreadsheet

I have an Excel worksheet used for product data entry.
Each individual product uses 16 rows.
Cells contain formulas, dropdown boxes that validate from another workbook and ListBoxes for multiple selection of items such as colours.

I need to copy the 16 rows to use as a template for a new product, and paste it below the previous, repeating this for each new product.

The dropdown boxes copy down fine as they are at cell level and allow each new product to have its own dropbox selection.

The issue is with copying/pasting the ListBoxes. As they are not connected to the cells, and become copies with new names, the code used for opening/closing them and outputting selections to a cell no longer works. Even if they remained with the same name they would only be relevant for the first product and not allow for individual data entry for each new product.

Here is the code used to control the ListBoxes

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.ListBox1
        If Target(1).Address = "$A$2" And .Visible = False Then
            .Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            [A3].Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            .Visible = False
            For I = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(I) Then txt = txt & ", " & .List(I)
            Next
            [A2] = Mid(txt, 2)  'remove first comma and output to A2 cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

ListBoxes seemed like a good solution for multiple selections while perfecting the spreadsheet for 1 dummy product, however I don't see how they could work in this application for each new product. Is there any other way to achieve this? Could a dropdown box be altered to have checkboxes for multiple selections as does a ListBox?

I have seen dropboxes used for multiple selections as per the method shown here:

[How to Make Multiple Selections in a Drop Down List in Excel](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/)

However there is no way to see which items are selected, other than seeing the output in the comma separated list, which could become quite a long list. The selections needs to be visible in the list itself with checkboxes.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is only a story which does not say anything, I'm afraid... Please, edit your question and post the pieces of code which look being problematic. Some pictures of the involved sheet(s) should also help. What kind of an answer would you suppose to receive based on the above story? Then, if the List Boxes solution looks great (for you), why don't you change the DropDown objects with such list boxes?

Comment: The listbox(es) in your 16-row product section have selections that are tied to cells within that 16-row section, right?  And then when you copy the section (and the listboxes), the listboxes are still linked back to the original section, not the new product section? Are you using code to create the new product section or copying manually?

Comment: @PeterT At this point I am copy/pasting the rows manually. Listbox 1 & 2 lare linked to the original section but they copy over to the new section as Listbox 3 and 4 and there is no longer any vba relevant to them. Even if they could remain the same name they wouldnt work independently for each product. I have edited the question to show an example.

Comment: @FaneDuru I have edited the question to show an example. The dropdown boxes are good because they are simple for single selections (such as Category) and require no code to work. They can be copied and pasted and act independently. The Listboxes are good because they allow multiple selections (such as Colour), however require code to work in a manner useful to me, and as it seems cannot be copied/pasted for each new product I wish to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I came up with does change the look of your listbox somewhat. You were using an ActiveX listbox that gives you the nice-looking checkboxes for your multiselect. The problem I had was assigning a macro to a listbox to catch the `OnAction` event (each time you click on a listbox item). My solution below works with Forms Listboxes. There are a few parts to the solution.

You stated a requirement that when the user selects a cell in the "Colours" column, a listbox pops up and presents the list of color options. To achieve this, I used the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event in the worksheet module:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    Dim colourRange As Range
    Set colourRange = ColourArea(ActiveSheet)
    If colourRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, colourRange) Is Nothing Then
        CreateColourPopUp Target
    Else
        DeleteAllPopUps Target
    End If
End Sub
```

What's important to note here is that the popup is created anytime the user selects a cell in the "Colours" column and whenever a cell is selected outside of that range, the popup is deleted. The `ColourArea` is defined in a separate module (with all the other code in this answer `Module1`):

```
Public Function ColourArea(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    '--- returns a range for the colour selections for all the products
    '    currently active on the worksheet
    Const COLOUR_COL As Long = 6
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        Set ColourArea = .Cells(2, COLOUR_COL).Resize(lastRow, 1)
    End With
End Function
```

I coded this as separate from the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` because you may now, or in the future, use some other way to determine what range on the worksheet is used for your colors.

Creating the popup then happens in the code here, where the listbox is created in the cell just below the selected cell. Note again that determining the range that contains the list of colors is encapsulated in a function.

```
Public Function ColourListArea() As Range
    Set ColourListArea = Sheet1.Range("M1:M11")
End Function

Public Sub DeleteAllPopUps(ByRef selectedCell As Range)
    Dim colourBox As ListBox
    For Each colourBox In selectedCell.Parent.ListBoxes
        colourBox.Delete
    Next colourBox
End Sub

Public Sub CreateColourPopUp(ByRef selectedCell As Range)
    Set colourSelectCell = selectedCell
    
    Dim popUpCell As Range
    Set popUpCell = colourSelectCell.OFFSET(1, 0)
    
    DeleteAllPopUps selectedCell

    '--- now create the one we need, right below the selected cell
    Const POPUP_WIDTH As Double = 75
    Const POPUP_HEIGHT As Double = 110
    Const OFFSET As Double = 5#
    Dim colourBox As ListBox
    Set colourBox = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(popUpCell.left + OFFSET, _
                                              popUpCell.top + OFFSET, _
                                              POPUP_WIDTH, _
                                              POPUP_HEIGHT)
    With colourBox
        .ListFillRange = ColourListArea().Address
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .MultiSelect = xlSimple
        .Display3DShading = True
        .OnAction = "Module1.ColourBoxClick"
    End With
    
    '--- is there an existing list of colours selected?
    Dim selectedColours() As String
    selectedColours = Split(colourSelectCell.Value, ",")
    Dim colour As Variant
    For Each colour In selectedColours
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To colourBox.ListCount
            If colourBox.List(i) = colour Then
                colourBox.Selected(i) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next colour
End Sub
```

The variable `colourSelectCell` is declared at the module-global level (see the full module at the end of this post). You will likely have to manually adjust the width and height constants as needed.

Finally, the `OnAction` routine is defined as:

```
Public Sub ColourBoxClick()
    Dim colourBoxName As String
    colourBoxName = Application.Caller
    
    Dim colourBox As ListBox
    Set colourBox = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes(colourBoxName)

    Dim colourList As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To colourBox.ListCount
        If colourBox.Selected(i) Then
            colourList = colourList & colourBox.List(i) & ","
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(colourList) > 0 Then
        colourList = Left$(colourList, Len(colourList) - 1)
    End If
    colourSelectCell.Value = colourList
End Sub
```

This is where the global `colourSelectCell` is used.

The entire `Module1` is

```
Option Explicit

Private colourSelectCell As Range

Public Function ColourArea(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Const COLOUR_COL As Long = 6
    '--- returns a range for the colour selections for all the products
    '    currently active on the worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
        If lastRow = 0 Then
            Set ColourArea = Nothing
        Else
            Set ColourArea = .Cells(2, COLOUR_COL).Resize(lastRow, 1)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub ColourBoxClick()
    Dim colourBoxName As String
    colourBoxName = Application.Caller
    
    Dim colourBox As ListBox
    Set colourBox = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes(colourBoxName)

    Dim colourList As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To colourBox.ListCount
        If colourBox.Selected(i) Then
            colourList = colourList & colourBox.List(i) & ","
        End If
    Next i
    If Len(colourList) > 0 Then
        colourList = Left$(colourList, Len(colourList) - 1)
    End If
    colourSelectCell.Value = colourList
End Sub

Public Function ColourListArea() As Range
    Set ColourListArea = Sheet1.Range("M1:M11")
End Function

Public Sub DeleteAllPopUps(ByRef selectedCell As Range)
    Dim colourBox As ListBox
    For Each colourBox In selectedCell.Parent.ListBoxes
        colourBox.Delete
    Next colourBox
End Sub

Public Sub CreateColourPopUp(ByRef selectedCell As Range)
    Set colourSelectCell = selectedCell
    
    Dim popUpCell As Range
    Set popUpCell = colourSelectCell.OFFSET(1, 0)
    
    DeleteAllPopUps selectedCell

    '--- now create the one we need, right below the selected cell
    Const POPUP_WIDTH As Double = 75
    Const POPUP_HEIGHT As Double = 110
    Const OFFSET As Double = 5#
    Dim colourBox As ListBox
    Set colourBox = ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(popUpCell.left + OFFSET, _
                                              popUpCell.top + OFFSET, _
                                              POPUP_WIDTH, _
                                              POPUP_HEIGHT)
    With colourBox
        .ListFillRange = ColourListArea().Address
        .LinkedCell = ""
        .MultiSelect = xlSimple
        .Display3DShading = True
        .OnAction = "Module1.ColourBoxClick"
    End With
    
    '--- is there an existing list of colours selected?
    Dim selectedColours() As String
    selectedColours = Split(colourSelectCell.Value, ",")
    Dim colour As Variant
    For Each colour In selectedColours
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To colourBox.ListCount
            If colourBox.List(i) = colour Then
                colourBox.Selected(i) = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
    Next colour
End Sub
```

> ***EDIT***: here's an example of returned a discontiguous range of cells to
> allow the popups. ***ALSO*** -- add the line `If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit  Sub` as shown to the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub so that you don't get errors selecting more than one cell.

```
Public Function ColourArea(ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    Const COLOUR_COL As Long = 6
    Const PRODUCT_ROWS As Long = 16
    '--- returns a range for the colour selections for all the products
    '    currently active on the worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow = 0 Then
            ColourArea = Nothing
        Else
            Dim numberOfProducts As Long
            numberOfProducts = (lastRow - 1) / PRODUCT_ROWS
        
            '--- now create a Union of the first row of each of these
            '    product areas
            Dim firstRow As Range
            Dim allFirsts As Range
            Set firstRow = ws.Cells(2, COLOUR_COL)
            Set allFirsts = firstRow
        
            Dim i As Long
            For i = 2 To numberOfProducts
                Set firstRow = firstRow.OFFSET(PRODUCT_ROWS, 0)
                Set allFirsts = Application.Union(allFirsts, firstRow)
            Next i
            Set ColourArea = allFirsts
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. I am having trouble getting it to work. I have placed the Private Sub only in Worksheet Selection Change and all else in a module. I was a little confused and tried both creating a Form Listbox and assigning the macro from the module to it, and assigning a linked cell, to then deleting the Listbox and assuming it was being created by the code itself. Its over my head! I am getting a runtime error 1004 and the highlighted line of code is `Set ColourArea = .Cells(2, COLOUR_COL).Resize(lastRow, 1)`

Comment: @ayecee - you should not have to create the listbox manually at all, the example code creates it for you. As for the error, my guess is that `lastRow` is coming up as zero, so you should change how that routine determines the actual area (column F? rows 2-16?). That function only exists to determine the range of cells in which the user must select colors for the product.

Comment: `Set ColourListArea = Sheet1.Range("M1:M11")` Am I correct that this would be the range for the colour validation list?

Comment: @ayecee - from your original image of your data, yes. That's the example I set up on my own worksheet.

Comment: Thanks I have this working now. The only issue I'm having is the colour list is showing when I click in every row. How can I amend it to only show in the first row of the 16 row group?This could be any number of rows, 16 is just an example.

Comment: Also getting a couple of errors. 1) If right clicking in the Excel column 'F' label, I get a 'Run-time error 1004: application-defined or object-defined error' 2) If clicking around a little too fast in column F cells I get a 'Run-time error 13: Type mismatch'

Comment: @ayecee - you restrict the rows in which the Sub runs in `Worksheet_SelectionChange` by adjusting the `Intersect` parameters. That's why the `ColourArea(ActiveSheet)` should return ONLY the cells that you want the popup to occur. So if it's returning `F2:F17`, those should be the only cells that generate the popup. If any other cell is selected, it should delete all existing popups.

Comment: I can see that `Const COLOUR_COL As Long = 7` restricts the pop up to the 7th column, column F. I cant see how to restrict the rows. How would I restrict it to the first row, keeping in mind each time a new product is added this row will have a different number ie. the first row of the 16 row block, row#2, 18, 34 etc

Comment: @ayecee - One of the reasons I create a function like `ColourArea` is for exactly your situation: to calculate which cells (ranges) should allow a popup. Based on your description, I think you need to determine how many products are visible on your worksheet (`lastRow / 16`?) and then create a disjointed range using `Union` to return all the "first rows of each product". As a (possible wrong) example, I added a sample function to the code above to give you an idea.

Comment: I may be overlooking it, but I have compared the previous code to the new code side by side and cant see where it has been added.

Comment: Thank you that did it. Only issue I'm having is that after making a selection in the pop up, when I try to remove the last remaining selection, I get a run-time error 5: invalid procedure call or argument, with this code highlighted `colourList = Left$(colourList, Len(colourList) - 1)`

Comment: @ayecee - You have to check to make sure the length of your string of colors is greater than zero, as in `If Len(colourList) > 0 Then`. See the additional code above.

Comment: Thank you, solved! I have realised my row situation may not always be 16 but If I cant get this to suit I will post a new question.

Comment: I know this is an old question but just thought if it was an easy fix it would be better than posting the whole code in a new question. The code works extremely well, except Ive just found when the sheet is blank and rows not yet added, except for header in row 1 I get a runtime error 1004: application-defined or object-defined. On this row `Set ColourArea = .Cells(2, COLOUR_COL).Resize(lastRow, 1)'

Comment: @ayecee - in that case, `lastRow` will be zero, so that is likely what's causing the error. You should put an `If` statement check before setting `ColourArea` to make sure you have a valid value of `lastRow`. If it's zero (the sheet is blank), the function should return `Nothing` -- which means the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` sub must check for that value before using it.

Comment: My noob attempt is `If lastRow = 0 Then Exit Function Else Set ColourArea = .Cells(2, COLOUR_COL).Resize(lastRow, 1)` which then brings up errors with `If Not Intersect(Target, ColourArea(ActiveSheet)) Is Nothing Then`. It may be better to post a new question!

Comment: @ayecee - I modified the code in the answer, both in `Worksheet_SelectionChange` and in `ColourArea` to show what to do.